# Attaching an object to an already existing ListItem?

Tags: delphi, listview, object, delphi-xe2, listitem

In a ListView, how can I attach an object at any time to an already existing ListItem? (I know I can attach an object to a ListItem with `AddItem`, however I need to attach the object after the ListItem has been created).

Comment: Rather than using `Data` you could use `OnCreateItemClass` and create your own dedicated subclass of `TListItem`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks. Do you have an example how to do this?

Comment: What are you storing in your list item?

Comment: @TLama Please undelete your answer. It's almost certainly the answer that should be accepted.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I need to store a TDateTime value. Thanks. (I don't want to store it in a subitem, I need to store it in an object).

Comment: How are you storing it at the moment? It doesn't fit in `Data` which is pointer sized.

Comment: @user - Your calling a TDateTime an object is quite inaccurate.

Comment: I don't store it at the moment, as I don't know how to add an object to a ListItem after it has been created, which was my original question. You said I could use `OnCreateItemClass`. Do you have an example for this?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I don't call a TDateTime an object. It should be clear that the TDateTime value is stored in a field within an object which I want to attach to the ListItem.

Comment: user - Ok then, @TLama provided an exact answer for that question. I don't know why he deleted it.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: I added a comment to another recent answer of TLama asking him to undelete...

Comment: Sorry guys, I've deleted my post since I was hoping for some more complex solution (and it's actually here :-) I couldn't be notified, since I didn't have any active post or comment in the whole thread.

Comment: @TLama More complex isn't necessarily better. If simple does the job, then it always wins. If associated object lifetime is not related to the item lifetime then Data property probably wins. If you need to tie lifetime to item lifetime then it's not so clear cut. Anyways, thanks for restoring your answer which  I already upvoted.

Comment: @TLama What David says, plus for reference purposes it isn't at all bad to have multiple answers offering alternate solutions to the problem. I often find that you are a bit too quick deleting your answers.

Comment: Yes, @TLama, as Marjan says, leave your answers around. You delete too many. You too often delete good answers, in my view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access it through the [`TListItem.Data`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListItem.Data) property. For example:

```
var
  ListItem: TListItem;
begin
  ListView1.AddItem('Item 1', nil);
  ...
  ListItem := ListView1.Items[0];
  ListItem.Data := Edit1;
  TEdit(ListItem.Data).Text := 'Updated text...';
end;
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to know how I can ATTACH an object to a ListItem AFTER it has been created, not how to ACCESS an object AFTER it has been attached with `AddItem`. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You could solve this using the `Data` property of `TListItem`. That's often a quick and easy approach. The only slight wrinkle is if you need the list items to manage the lifetime of their associated data. In that case you have to implement an `OnDeletion` event handler to finalize the associated data when a node is destroyed.

An alternative approach is to use a subclass of `TListItem`. First define your subclass:

```
type
  TMyListItem = class(TListItem)
  private
    FDateTime: TDateTime;
  public
    property DateTime: TDateTime read FDateTime write FDateTime;
  end;
```

Then implement a handler for the list view's `OnCreateNodeClass` event. This determines the actual class of list item that the list view instantiates.

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1CreateItemClass(Sender: TCustomListView; 
  var ItemClass: TListItemClass);
begin
  ItemClass := TMyListItem;
end;
```

Now the list view will create items of class `TMyListItem`.

So, you can simply access a list item's `DateTime` property as you would any other property.  Of course this approach can be extended to store more information.

The only other point to make is that the list view control will still offer you items that are compile time typed as being `TListItem`. So you will need to up-cast.

For example, suppose you wanted to do something when an item was edited. The event handler looks like this:

```
procedure ListView1Edited(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem; var S: string);
```

Note that the item is passed as type `TListItem`. So you would need to write it like this:

```
procedure TForm1.ListView1Edited(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem; 
  var S: string);
var
  MyItem: TMyListItem;
begin
  MyItem := Item as TMyListItem;
  if MyItem.DateTime ....
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, David, for this nice and extensive explanation of the alternative approach! However, when using the CreateItemClass alternative, what happens when the user deletes an item? Will the ListView also handle and destroy my added custom data fields? (E.g. FDateTime).

Comment: Yes it will. It will call Free on the item and your field will get disposed of just like any field in an object is.

Comment: Do I NEED to up-cast the Item parameter in ALL ListView method implementations, or only where I need to access my custom data field?

Comment: Only where you need to access your fields. I would like to say that the `Data` property is likely your most simple solution. If you already have objects in existence that hold the extra information, and if those objects have lifetime that is already managed, then `Data` is probably the best solution.

Comment: As I will create objects from my own class, I will try your alternative solution, so I will not have to manage the lifetime of the items, which seems the most valid advantage to me - beside the ease of use. Thanks.